# Aurora PostgreSQL queries fail with error "Attempted to read past the end of the stream" after removal of a reader instance

Tags: postgresql, .net-6.0, npgsql, amazon-aurora

I've been running queries on an **Aurora PostgreSQL** cluster having 1 writer instance and 1 reader instance.
My application is in .**NET6** and it's using the **Npgsql** library to connect to the cluster. I've been testing with multiple versions of the library: 6.0.7 and 7.0.0.

Here is the scenario:

1. I executed queries using the cluster's reader endpoint (load balancer).
2. In the metrics all connections appeared on the reader instance.
3. Added another reader instance to the cluster.
4. Once the new reader instance was up and running, some of the new queries may have been transferred to the new reader, but sometimes all queries were still executing on the first reader.
5. **I removed the first reader instance from the AWS Management Console. At this point I expected that all new queries are executed on the newly added reader since the first one was getting deleted.**
6. But usually most of the queries were still executed on the first one.
7. While the original reader was being deleted, queries executed fine for a while, but at some point the reader was deleted and queries failed with error:

**Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.**

Shouldn't new queries (using a newly created NpgSqlConection object) execute on the second reader as soon as the first one is marked to be deleted?
Can someone provide some details on how this should be done? Can this be avoided without using a retry mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue when rebooting the primary instance. Even after the primary instance was rebooted, the first few requests would go to the old instance which was resulting in the same error.

I added the Keepalive=1 parameter to the postgres connection string and found that the stale connections were removed and replaced with clean ones. Issue was resolved after